# UIStatusBar has different color

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I have to set a mask on the navigation bar that I can animate the icons down out of the bar. After I set the mask the status bar is black. Therefore I set a View under the status bar.

I copy exactly the colour properties from the status bar but nevertheless is the colour different. Any idea why? Any idea for a solution?

I tested on iOS 7.0 & 7.1

Cheers!

```
    self.navBar = self.viewController.navigationController.navigationBar;
    self.navBar.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIToolbar * statusBarBg = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 22)];
    statusBarBg.barTintColor   = self.navBar.barTintColor;
    statusBarBg.tintColor      = self.navBar.tintColor;
    statusBarBg.translucent    = self.navBar.translucent;
    statusBarBg.backgroundColor = self.navBar.backgroundColor;

    [self.navBar.superview addSubview:statusBarBg];
```

[image]

Comment: What is your statusBar style?

Comment: This is not the point. If I generate a UIToolbar or a UIView with the same colour properties is the colour different.

Comment: You should think instead about why the black appears behind the status bar. The navigation bar is supposed to extend up behind the status bar.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: Year I did. I think it was the "translucent" set it to false

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Saved me a lot of headache :)